# Data type of columns are differ in glue data catalog and getCatalogSource function

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

I created a glue crawler to read apache access logs.Below is table definition which crawler created it in Glue data catalog.I was able to get the below DDL statement from Athena.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE crawler_access_log(
.. Other column names
timestamp string COMMENT 'from deserializer'
) ROW FORMAT SERDE 
'com.amazonaws.glue.serde.GrokSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
'input.format'='%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
's3://some location'
TBLPROPERTIES (
'CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion'='1.0', 
'CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion'='1.0', 
'UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER'='crawler_access_log', 
'averageRecordSize'='268', 
'classification'='combinedapache', 
'compressionType'='gzip', 
'grokPattern'='%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}', 
'objectCount'='2', 
'recordCount'='71552', 
'sizeKey'='25268746', 
'typeOfData'='file')

//SAMPLE TIMESTAMP (Data type as string) COULMN DATA
 20/Jul/2018:03:27:44 +0000
 20/Jul/2018:03:27:44 +0000
```

But when I am reading the data from the same table through glueContext the datatype of the `timestamp` column becomes `date` instead of `string`.I am using the below code to read the data from the table.

```
val rawDynamicDataFrame = glueContext.getCatalogSource(database = "someDB", 
tableName = "crawler_access_log", redshiftTmpDir = "", transformationContext 
= "rawDynamicDataFrame").getDynamicFrame();
```

When I do the printSchema and see data of the dynamic data frame,I see the `timestamp` column has the datatype as `date` instead of `string`.Hence the data gets truncated.

```
scala> rawDynamicDataFrame.printSchema
root
|-- xx: string
|-- xx: string
|-- xx: string
|-- timestamp: date
|-- xx: string
|-- xx: string
|-- xx: string
scala> rawDynamicDataFrame.show(2)
2018-07-20  ///Original (20/Jul/2018:03:27:44 +0000)
2018-07-20  ///Original (20/Jul/2018:03:27:44 +0000)
```

I am not able to figure out why the data types are changing even though the glue reads the data from glue catalog.